# Draw rectangle with connection point using Raphael

Tags: raphael

i'm trying to draw a rectangle with 4 connection points in each edges ( not in the corners). Like this :

[image]

Because laterly I need to use mouse event on them.

Comment: Can you rephrase this into the form of a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amadanNM/LG5zn/) what you're looking for?

Comment: yes , thank you. The question was not completed because my internet was disconnected when I was editing.